# Should I use rel="canonical" on my homepage for non www to www?

Tags: html, tags, seo

I'm really confused about using the `rel="canonical"` on my homepage since my website is using www and non www. Should I be using

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/" />`

on my homepage since i prefer www, for when someone accesses my domain using a non-www?

Comment: You should redirect any non-www requests to www.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Machavity Your right, thanks. I didn't know about webmasters.se before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use canonical url on non-www version to avoid duplicated content problem. And this is true not for homepage but for every page of your website that can be opened with or without www subdomain.

But more preferable way to solve the problem is to configure 302 moved permanentrly redirect instead of rel="canonical". You can do this using your webserver config or .htaccess files.

Read more about how google handles duplicated content in their help article here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en